Optimizing SQL query for use with Access (Passthrough)
I'm attempting to optimize a SQL query I've built I use as a passthrough query in Access. Currently this query can take up to 10 minutes to complete and I'd really like to shave that time down. I realize that a big part of the problem is that I have a lot of internal queries inside other internal queries. This is because my company won't give me permissions to create any permanent tables.
I have a version of this query where I transfer a lot of the "mess" of internal queries to a temp table instead and call on that but that doesn't work as a passthrough query for Access. Not unless it's run during every session when the access db is opened.
I'd really like to try to find a way to make this work as just a straight query in SQL that I can use as a passthrough in Access.
Here is the SQL:
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#catcov1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #catcov1;
SELECT a.mailyear,
       a.offer,
       a.description,
       a.InternetActiveDate,
       a.FirstReleaseMailed,
       a.season_id,
       a.offer_type,
       a.price_type,
       b.Prefix_Quarter,
       a.CompanyCode AS Brand_Code,
       CASE WHEN CompanyCode = '1' THEN 'Company 1'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '2' THEN 'Company 2'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '3' THEN 'Company 3'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '4' THEN 'Company 4'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '5' THEN 'Company 5'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '6' THEN 'Company 6'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '7' THEN 'Company 7'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '8' THEN 'Company 8'
           WHEN CompanyCode = '9' THEN 'Company 9'
           ELSE CompanyCode
       END AS Brand_Name
INTO #catcov1
FROM CatCov a
     JOIN offer_placement b ON (a.Offer = b.offer)
                           AND (a.MailYear = b.offeryear)
WHERE (CASE WHEN Description LIKE '%test%' THEN 0
           WHEN Description LIKE '%Price%A%' THEN 0
           WHEN Description LIKE '%Price%B%' THEN 0
           WHEN Description LIKE '%Amazon.com%' THEN 0
           WHEN Description LIKE '%EB Discount%' THEN 0
           ELSE 1
       END) = 1
  AND a.Offer_Type IN ('Catalog', 'Insert', 'Kicker', 'Statement Insert', 'Bangtail', 'Onsert', 'Outside Ad', 'Blow In');

SELECT DISTINCT
       a.PackNum,
       a.Description,
       a.CatID,
       CONCAT(a.PackNum, a.CatID) AS [Key],
       CONCAT(a.rd, a.sfc) AS RDSFC,
       b.Season_Id,
       b.Brand_Name,
       b.Description AS CatCovDesc,
       b.FirstReleaseMailed AS MailDate,
       b.Prefix_Quarter,
       a.retone AS Retail,
       a.ret2 AS EBRetail,
       a.OriginalRetail,
       a.DiscountReasonCode AS DRC,
       hr.LastHigh AS LastHigh,
       ct.New_Retail1 AS New_Retail,
       ct.EB_High,
       ct.Catalog,
       ct.Original_Retail,
       ct.DRC AS New_DRC,
       ct.Requested,
       ct.Request_Completed_Date,
       ct.Notes,
       ct.Season,
       m.Merch AS MerchMgr,
       t.MerchAssistants
FROM PIC704Current a
     JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                    AND (a.year = b.mailyear)
     FULL JOIN CIDRetailChangeTracking ct ON (a.PackNum = ct.Pack)
                                         AND (a.CatID = ct.Catalog)
                                         AND (b.Season_Id = ct.Season)
     FULL JOIN MerchantCodes m ON (a.TwoDigitMerchCode = m.MerchCode)
     JOIN SupplyChain_Misc.flex_tbl_merchcode t ON (m.MerchCode = t.MerchCode)
     FULL JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                       a.PackNum,
                       MAX(q.IAD) AS [Last High Date],
                       MAX(q.MaxRetail) AS MaxRetail,
                       MIN(q.MinRetail) AS MinRetail,
                       q.LastHigh
                FROM PIC704Current a
                     JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                                    AND (a.Year = b.MailYear)
                     JOIN (SELECT b.PackNum,
                                  MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date)) AS IAD,
                                  CASE WHEN retone >= ret2
                                        AND retone >= originalretail THEN Retone
                                      WHEN Ret2 >= RetOne
                                       AND Ret2 >= originalretail THEN Ret2
                                      WHEN Originalretail >= ret2
                                       AND Originalretail >= Retone THEN Originalretail
                                  END AS MaxRetail,
                                  CASE WHEN retone >= ret2
                                        AND retone >= originalretail THEN Retone
                                      WHEN Ret2 >= RetOne
                                       AND Ret2 >= originalretail THEN Ret2
                                      WHEN Originalretail >= ret2
                                       AND Originalretail >= Retone THEN Originalretail
                                  END AS MinRetail,
                                  LH.LastHigh
                           FROM #catcov1 a
                                JOIN PIC704Current b ON (a.offer = b.CatID)
                                                    AND (a.MailYear = b.year)
                                FULL JOIN (SELECT PackNum,
                                                  MAX(CAST(firstreleasemailed AS date)) AS Maildate,
                                                  CASE WHEN MAX(a.RetOne) >= MAX(a.ret2)
                                                        AND MAX(a.RetOne) >= MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) THEN MAX(a.RetOne)
                                                      WHEN MAX(a.ret2) >= MAX(a.RetOne)
                                                       AND MAX(a.ret2) >= MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) THEN MAX(a.ret2)
                                                      WHEN MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) >= MAX(a.ret2)
                                                       AND MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) >= MAX(a.RetOne) THEN MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL)
                                                  END AS LastHigh
                                           FROM pic704current a
                                                JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                                                               AND (a.Year = b.MailYear)
                                                JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                                                             b.offer,
                                                             b.mailyear
                                                      FROM #catcov1 b) q ON (a.CatID = q.offer)
                                                                        AND (a.Year = q.MailYear)
                                           WHERE ( CAST(b.firstreleasemailed AS date) <= GETDATE()
                                                OR b.FirstReleaseMailed IS NULL)
                                           GROUP BY PackNum) LH ON (b.PackNum = LH.PackNum)
                           WHERE (CAST(a.InternetActiveDate AS date) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date))
                                                                        FROM #catcov1 c2
                                                                        WHERE (a.offer = c2.Offer)
                                                                          AND (a.MailYear = c2.MailYear)))
                             AND a.Season_Id = 'F24'
                           GROUP BY b.PackNum,
                                    RetOne,
                                    Ret2,
                                    ORIGINALRETAIL,
                                    LH.LastHigh) q ON (a.PackNum = q.PackNum)
                                                  AND (b.InternetActiveDate = q.IAD)
                WHERE a.RD >= 50
                  AND (CAST(b.InternetActiveDate AS date) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date))
                                                             FROM #catcov1 c2
                                                             WHERE (b.offer = c2.Offer)
                                                               AND (b.MailYear = c2.MailYear)))
                GROUP BY a.PackNum,
                         LastHigh) hr ON (a.PackNum = hr.PackNum)
WHERE RD >= 50
  AND b.Season_Id = 'F24'
  AND ( CAST(ct.Request_Completed_Date AS datetime) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(Request_Completed_Date AS datetime))
                                                       FROM CIDRetailChangeTracking c2
                                                       WHERE ct.[key] = c2.[key])
     OR ct.Request_Completed_Date IS NULL)
GROUP BY a.PackNum,
         a.Description,
         a.CatID,
         a.rd,
         a.sfc,
         b.Season_Id,
         b.Brand_Name,
         b.Description,
         b.FirstReleaseMailed,
         b.Prefix_Quarter,
         hr.MaxRetail,
         hr.MinRetail,
         hr.LastHigh,
         a.retone,
         a.ret2,
         a.OriginalRetail,
         a.DiscountReasonCode,
         ct.New_Retail1,
         ct.EB_High,
         ct.Catalog,
         ct.Original_Retail,
         ct.DRC,
         ct.Requested,
         ct.Request_Completed_Date,
         ct.Notes,
         ct.Season,
         m.Merch,
         t.MerchAssistants
HAVING hr.MaxRetail <> hr.MinRetail
ORDER BY Packnum,
         MailDate;


Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) "a" is for CatCov, and "b" is for "offer_placement" (what "b"?) is really confusing. Use meaningful alias. CC and OP would seem sensible here, for example.

can you share query plan for your query https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

The DISTINCT and GROUP BY "smells". Why are you using a DISTINCT when you have a GROUP BY, so your query is already returning the data in distinct groups? Why do you have a GROUP BY when you have no aggregation? It looks like neither DISTINCT or GROUP BY belong in that query, and are likely part of the larger problem, as those operations are likely to be quite expensive.

Factoring out some of these subqueries into temp tables can help make this more modular and testable, and give you the chance to index the temp tables.

@ThomA Using Distinct because there are instances when there are duplicate records and only want to see one. The Group BY is necessary because I am using aggregation when asking for max retails and min retail. Tried this without the group by's but SSMS won't allow it unless the group by is there. Also I realize it's messy with my current alias's but that's something I can clean up later.

@rahulc I'll see if I can get them in there. I've never had to send query plans before but I do have them.

@Deke you aren't aggregating though. Look at your final SELECT: db<>fiddle. A DISTINCT with a GROUP BY is always a sign of a flaw in your query. As I already stated GROUP BY already causes your data to be returned in distinct sets. More than likely you are getting duplicates because your JOINs are wrong.

@ThomA Thanks I'll start figuring that out. It gives me a good place to start in trying to get this optimized. Really appreciate your insight and help! I should note I'm self taught so I'm still trying to learn everything I can.

Are you sure about all those multiple FULL JOINs? I've done my fair share of sql programming, but have hard time "compiling" a query with more than one FULL JOIN, so it looks a bit suspicious to me.

The following should tidy up the code a bit.
Also, what is the data type and format for all your dates. All the casting to date and datetime is not going to help.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#catcov1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #catcov1;
SELECT a.mailyear,
       a.offer,
       a.description,
       a.InternetActiveDate,
       a.FirstReleaseMailed,
       a.season_id,
       a.offer_type,
       a.price_type,
       b.Prefix_Quarter,
       a.CompanyCode AS Brand_Code,
       CASE WHEN CompanyCode BETWEEN '1' AND '9' THEN CONCAT('Company ', CompanyCode)
           ELSE CompanyCode
       END AS Brand_Name
INTO #catcov1
FROM CatCov a
     JOIN offer_placement b ON (a.Offer = b.offer)
                           AND (a.MailYear = b.offeryear)
WHERE Description NOT LIKE '%test%'
  AND Description NOT LIKE '%Price%A%'
  AND Description NOT LIKE '%Price%B%'
  AND Description NOT LIKE '%Amazon.com%'
  AND Description NOT LIKE '%EB Discount%'
  AND a.Offer_Type IN ('Catalog', 'Insert', 'Kicker', 'Statement Insert', 'Bangtail', 'Onsert', 'Outside Ad', 'Blow In');

SELECT DISTINCT
       a.PackNum,
       a.Description,
       a.CatID,
       CONCAT(a.PackNum, a.CatID) AS [Key],
       CONCAT(a.rd, a.sfc) AS RDSFC,
       b.Season_Id,
       b.Brand_Name,
       b.Description AS CatCovDesc,
       b.FirstReleaseMailed AS MailDate,
       b.Prefix_Quarter,
       a.retone AS Retail,
       a.ret2 AS EBRetail,
       a.OriginalRetail,
       a.DiscountReasonCode AS DRC,
       hr.LastHigh AS LastHigh,
       ct.New_Retail1 AS New_Retail,
       ct.EB_High,
       ct.Catalog,
       ct.Original_Retail,
       ct.DRC AS New_DRC,
       ct.Requested,
       ct.Request_Completed_Date,
       ct.Notes,
       ct.Season,
       m.Merch AS MerchMgr,
       t.MerchAssistants
FROM PIC704Current a
     JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                    AND (a.year = b.mailyear)
     FULL JOIN CIDRetailChangeTracking ct ON (a.PackNum = ct.Pack)
                                         AND (a.CatID = ct.Catalog)
                                         AND (b.Season_Id = ct.Season)
     FULL JOIN MerchantCodes m ON (a.TwoDigitMerchCode = m.MerchCode)
     JOIN SupplyChain_Misc.flex_tbl_merchcode t ON (m.MerchCode = t.MerchCode)
     FULL JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                       a.PackNum,
                       MAX(q.IAD) AS [Last High Date],
                       MAX(q.MaxRetail) AS MaxRetail,
                       MIN(q.MinRetail) AS MinRetail,
                       q.LastHigh
                FROM PIC704Current a
                     JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                                    AND (a.Year = b.MailYear)
                     JOIN (SELECT b.PackNum,
                                  MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date)) AS IAD,
                                  CASE WHEN retone >= ret2
                                        AND retone >= originalretail THEN Retone
                                      WHEN Ret2 >= RetOne
                                       AND Ret2 >= originalretail THEN Ret2
                                      WHEN Originalretail >= ret2
                                       AND Originalretail >= Retone THEN Originalretail
                                  END AS MaxRetail,
                                  CASE WHEN retone >= ret2
                                        AND retone >= originalretail THEN Retone
                                      WHEN Ret2 >= RetOne
                                       AND Ret2 >= originalretail THEN Ret2
                                      WHEN Originalretail >= ret2
                                       AND Originalretail >= Retone THEN Originalretail
                                  END AS MinRetail,
                                  LH.LastHigh
                           FROM #catcov1 a
                                JOIN PIC704Current b ON (a.offer = b.CatID)
                                                    AND (a.MailYear = b.year)
                                FULL JOIN (SELECT PackNum,
                                                  MAX(CAST(firstreleasemailed AS date)) AS Maildate,
                                                  CASE WHEN MAX(a.RetOne) >= MAX(a.ret2)
                                                        AND MAX(a.RetOne) >= MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) THEN MAX(a.RetOne)
                                                      WHEN MAX(a.ret2) >= MAX(a.RetOne)
                                                       AND MAX(a.ret2) >= MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) THEN MAX(a.ret2)
                                                      WHEN MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) >= MAX(a.ret2)
                                                       AND MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL) >= MAX(a.RetOne) THEN MAX(a.ORIGINALRETAIL)
                                                  END AS LastHigh
                                           FROM pic704current a
                                                JOIN #catcov1 b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer)
                                                               AND (a.Year = b.MailYear)
                                                JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                                                             b.offer,
                                                             b.mailyear
                                                      FROM #catcov1 b) q ON (a.CatID = q.offer)
                                                                        AND (a.Year = q.MailYear)
                                           WHERE ( CAST(b.firstreleasemailed AS date) <= GETDATE()
                                                OR b.FirstReleaseMailed IS NULL)
                                           GROUP BY PackNum) LH ON (b.PackNum = LH.PackNum)
                           WHERE (CAST(a.InternetActiveDate AS date) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date))
                                                                        FROM #catcov1 c2
                                                                        WHERE (a.offer = c2.Offer)
                                                                          AND (a.MailYear = c2.MailYear)))
                             AND a.Season_Id = 'F24'
                           GROUP BY b.PackNum,
                                    RetOne,
                                    Ret2,
                                    ORIGINALRETAIL,
                                    LH.LastHigh) q ON (a.PackNum = q.PackNum)
                                                  AND (b.InternetActiveDate = q.IAD)
                WHERE a.RD >= 50
                  AND (CAST(b.InternetActiveDate AS date) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(InternetActiveDate AS date))
                                                             FROM #catcov1 c2
                                                             WHERE (b.offer = c2.Offer)
                                                               AND (b.MailYear = c2.MailYear)))
                GROUP BY a.PackNum,
                         LastHigh) hr ON (a.PackNum = hr.PackNum)
WHERE RD >= 50
  AND b.Season_Id = 'F24'
  AND ( CAST(ct.Request_Completed_Date AS datetime) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(Request_Completed_Date AS datetime))
                                                       FROM CIDRetailChangeTracking c2
                                                       WHERE ct.[key] = c2.[key])
     OR ct.Request_Completed_Date IS NULL)
     AND hr.MaxRetail <> hr.MinRetail
ORDER BY Packnum,
         MailDate;

